# Serving static files 'conditionally' in in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have done many projects in Django and I'm used to the normal way of serving static files. However, I have a different scenario this time, where there are sub-folders within the templates folder(e.g there are folders page1/, page2/ etc. within the template folder). Each of those folders contains the template file "index.html" and then static files(css, js and images  folders).

My question is, how can I get to serve each template with their corresponding static files.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But why have you put the static files in with the templates? Those are completely different things and served in completely different ways.

Comment: The app is in such a way that the templates are somehow separated from the app...even maintained in separate repos...all that remains constant is the data being passed to the templates. I also hate to have such an organisation...trust me!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to include the static file like any other template. Albeit, this is not the ideal approach for using static assets and is highly unorthodox for django.

One approach would be to have a block in the head and bottom of the body for extra css and extra js, respectively in your base html file. From there, you can call the block in your index.html and include your static file.

for example, in page1/index.html

```
{% block extra_css %}
<style>
  {% include 'page1/mycss.css' %}
</style>
{% endblock extra_css %}
```

Again, i would never personally do this. Using static files and referencing them is the way to go.